# Complex query in elastic using Kibana

Tags: lucene, kibana, kibana-5

Say I have many documents, one document may indicate a door opening, another a door closing, each of these has a doorID field.

I would like to write a query that would return all the cases where a door both opened and closed.

There are doors that "just" opened, or "just closed - those are not interesting to me.

I want only open-closed pairs, based on ID.

How would I create that "connection" between both documents in lucene syntax?

Comment: Do you know doorID?

Comment: DoorID is not a constant, there are many Door IDs